# Spotfire - Fix columns order in DataTable

Tags: spotfire

There are few columns in my Spotfire data table with column names (Month-6, Month-5, Month-4, Month-3, Month-2, Month-1).

**Explanation:** Month-1 is CurrentMonth-1 ie., Feb 2017. 
Month-2 is CurrentMonth-2 ie., Jan 2017 respectively. For next month (Apr'17), Month-1 will become Mar 2017 and Month-2 will become Feb 2017.

For the benefit of the users, I am running a 'change column names' transformation on the table using the below case statement.

```
case  
when [%C]="Month-6" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-6,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-6,DateTimeNow()))) 
when [%C]="Month-5" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-5,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-5,DateTimeNow()))) 
when [%C]="Month-4" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-4,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-4,DateTimeNow()))) 
when [%C]="Month-3" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-3,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-3,DateTimeNow()))) 
when [%C]="Month-2" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-2,DateTimeNow()))) 
when [%C]="Month-1" then concatenate(Month(dateadd("mm",-1,DateTimeNow()))," ",Year(dateadd("mm",-1,DateTimeNow())))
else "" end
```

I gave a specific order to these columns as how they should appear in the table.Example: Month-6 should start first and end with Month-1.

This works fine for the current month. But, on 1st of next month when the month names change, columns order get disturbed. I have to re-order them manually.

Is there a way I can permanently fix the order of columns?

Thank you!